# How to get the Medic! achievement after it was removed and reset upon reconnecting to XBL?

Tags: achievements, fear

Okay, I know the game is old, but on the verge of next gen consoles there's a chance older games will get the server axe.

I played the game offline for a few years and obtained most of the offline achievements, when I finally connected to XBL, some of my achievements were removed and reset, one of them was "Medic! Use 50 medkits in the campaign or instant action", I recently decided to finish the game 100%, I played through the campaign 3 times and the "Medic!" Did not pop.

I tried to recover my gamertag, I played offline and cleared my cache, nothing worked, so am I screwed out of 5 gamerscore?

Answer (score 1):

Afraid so. I had the same problem in the past with a game (Mortal Kombat vs DC Universe) and I had to remove the save entirely and rebeat the game from start to finish. VERY irritating, I also had issues with another game that escapes me but I want to say that it was Assassins creed and I chose to run the gambit again for that achievement as well. Occasionally you'll get lucky and it will pop on an update (Thank you The Outfit) but it has been very rare that those achievements will occur.

Comment: I'm not sure of an update in the near future, seeing how Microsoft is with their products...

Comment: yeah unfortunately its a mixture between devs and microsoft. but look at the bright side! you'll at least be able to beat fear for a 4th time right?! :p

Comment: Oh well, the other achievements aren't glitched except for "No Fear", plus I've got another 57 games to attempt a 100% completition on, once I get at least 80% complete in total, I'm ditching Xbox for the Playstation 4 :p haha